# Populating listview from arraylist

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to populate a list view with an array list. The array list is fetched from a soap web service response. 
I have used it as following:

```
mylistview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Plant>(MainActivity.this,
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_books);
mylistview.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

It display following in list view:

```
Book{id=1; name= C++; imagepath=https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GW3ixVIGHLrrXb2yN_6i;}

Book{id=2; name= Java; imagepath=https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GW3ixVyN_6i;}

Book{id=3; name=Android; imagepath=https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GW3HLrrXb2yN_6i;}
```

I want to display the image by retrieving it from its path in Image View and display only name of book like:
image ................ Java

When I change the layout in

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Book>(MainActivity.this,
                 android.R.layout.row, array_books);
```

it gives error that row cannot resolved as a resource. But row.xml is present in the layout folder. How can I correct this error and display the items I want in the list view?

Comment: Try to change android.R.layout.row to R.layout.row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Plant>(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.row, array_books);// Change  android.R.layout.row to R.layout.row
```

Your row is present in your `layout` so need to find using `R.layout.row`

Comment: It worked. And how to get only particular part of array list like only book name.??

Comment: @user3823856 you need override toString() method on `Plant` class then return anything you want like " `return title;` "

Comment: @user3823856 I didn't get you. What are you talking about?

Comment: @user3823856 use a custom adapter in that case.

Comment: Ok. Thanks to you all.

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA do ask a new question

Comment: @Raghunandan Yeah i know but it is too long code to show you and i just want to know one thing from you.

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA Hi guys.. What's going on here??

Comment: @Raghunandan see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774840/google-map-show-south-africa-as-current-location

Answer (score 0):

Use R.layout.row instead of android.R.layout.row

Answer (score 0):

As @Giru pointed out, if your xml file row.xml is in your layout folder, you can't reference it by android.R

The android.R object has references to the resources bundled with Android.

Your resources are simply under your.package.R so in your file just remove the "android." and have

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Plant>(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.row, array_books);
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: You all pointed out my mistake correctly. And how to get only particular part of array list like only book name.??